# How do I verify the order of MANIFEST.MF within jar?

Tags: java, jar, packaging

I've run into interesting problem which is absolutely new to me. As I've suddenly discovered, Jar specification says that, being included, `META-INF` and `MANIFEST.MF` must be first and second entries of `*.jar` package and not just directory and file within archive.

I'm working with Java framework being very watchful about this requirement and not as much verbose. How do I check that `META-INF` and `MANIFEST.MF` are properly ordered within jar?

**UPDATE:**
Many of jars are third-party, and there are many of them. I'm not able to open these jars in notepad, excel, hexeditor, photoshop or whatever looking for byte sequences. I need command-line tool. Thanks!

**UPDATE 2:**
Here is the reason why I'm asking this question: 
http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@felix.apache.org/msg17097.html

Comment: Actually the specification does NOT say that they must be first. However the `jar` command line tool does place them first and some tools expect them to be, for example because a tool could quickly scan the manifests from an entire directory of JAR files. So it's really more of a convention than a requirement.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett, thanks for clarification, but it makes things worse for me :( Here is the source of the problem: http://www.mail-archive.com/dev@felix.apache.org/msg17097.html Any ideas?

Comment: Aha, so this is an instance of a tool assuming the MANIFEST comes first! To answer your original question, `jar tf foo.jar` should list the contents of the JAR in order.

Comment: @Neil Bartlett, thanks, working. Could you post it as reply along with disclosure of misleading "specification" ? Btw, just checked my Intellij Idea 10 war artifact builder - META-INF goes after WEB-INF, wtf? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following command will list the contents of a JAR in order:

```
jar tf foo.jar
```

Note that there is no actual requirement in the JAR specification for `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to appear first. However JARs built by the `jar` tool (supplied with the JDK) **do** have the manifest first, and therefore it has become a convention.

Comment: I also can't see the requirement in the spec ... but then the standard library in the form of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html#getManifest() *does* make use of that constraint (without saying so). E.g. if you by any chance have reordered the entries (obfuscation, uber jar, ...) `getManifest` might just return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The jar tool with the JDK automatically adds them first, so there shouldn't be anything you have to do. If you really want to check, get a hex editor and look for the strings 'META-INF' and 'MANIFEST.MF' before any other file names.

Comment: Thanks, might be helpful in some cases, what about command line tools?

Comment: For hex editing? I don't really know about command line tools for it, but you might also be able to simply open it with Notepad and look for the strings there, it just won't be as pretty as with a hex editor.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think there is a command to do that, sorry. EDIT: Actually, try the -t option for `jar`. From the jar help: "-t  list table of contents for the archive"

Comment: yes, thanks, Neil already answered, should have guessed it by myself

Answer (score 2):

To fix the broken JARs:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ jar xvf ../broken.jar
$ mv META-INF/MANIFEST.MF /tmp/mymanifest
$ jar cvfm fixed.jar /tmp/mymanifest .
```

SEE: [MANIFEST.MF must be the first resource in a jar file – here’s how to fix broken jars](http://grep.codeconsult.ch/2011/11/15/manifest-mf-must-be-the-first-resource-in-a-jar-file-heres-how-to-fix-broken-jars/)

Comment: To fix the FileNotFoundException: jar cvfm fixed.jar /tmp/mymanifest/MANIFEST.MF .