# Unzip+Zip Jar => getManifest == null

Tags: jar, manifest.mf

```
unzip ../test.jar
zip -r ../test2.jar *
```

Using JarInputStream.getManifest() I can read the Manifest from test.jar but NOT from test2.jar where it returns null.

However if I recreate the jar using 'jar':

```
jar cf ../test3.jar .
```

I can get the Manifest on test3.jar.

Isn't zipping equivalent to jar? Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I verify the order of MANIFEST.MF within jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727637/how-do-i-verify-the-order-of-manifest-mf-within-jar). In short: manifest should be the first entries in the file, something that's obviously respected by the jar tool but not by zip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JarInputStream retuns null for existing Manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514926/jarinputstream-retuns-null-for-existing-manifest-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
jar -cvfm test.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF .
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.